# Emacs slow when inserting large strings

Tags: windows, emacs

Whenever I'm copy-and-pasting large amounts of data between buffers, my Emacs gets seriously slow. While I'm writing this, I've been waiting for several minutes for it to process the insertion of a single 10MB line into a file. Is that normal behaviour or is there something I can do about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Emacs has a performance problem with very long lines: see bug report [here](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=13675)

Try breaking the data into shorter lines if possible.

Comment: @user46627 The less work the redisplay code has to do on a buffer containing long lines, the less slow it'll be; `M-x fundamental-mode` in the buffer before pasting will therefore mitigate the problem at least somewhat.